# What is the value of a Char in java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, char

Let's say I have a `String`. If I do this:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < ch.length(); index++) {
            char c = ch.charAt(index);
            System.out.println(String.format("%04x", (int) c));
    }
```

What will the output be ?

I tried `a` and got `0061`, which seems to be the UTF-8/ASCII value of `A`.
Then I tried  and got `d800 dd51` which seems not to be a UTF value.

Just wondering, what is the int value of a `Char` in Java.

Comment: [_Character literals can only represent UTF-16 code units (§3.1), i.e., they are limited to values from `\u0000` to `\uffff`. Supplementary characters must be represented either as a surrogate pair within a char sequence, or as an integer, depending on the API they are used with._](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4)

Comment: In other words, a Java `Char` is a single UTF-16 codeunit (not a character), and a `String` is a sequence of UTF-16 codeunits.  In UTF-16, Unicode codepoints `U+0000` to `U+FFFF` use 1 codeunit, and codepoints `U+10000` to `U+10FFFF` use 2 codeunits, called a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ch variable in your for loop is a `String` type and you want to access each character in that then cast it to it's ascii value? Well that's what your code does. I ran it after making minor corrections and using `String ch = "abcdef"` and it gave me the out put of:

```
0061
0062
0063
0064
0065
0066
```

Which is exactly what your print statement instructs:

-cast the character to its' ascii value

-output four character long value.

If it helps, the ascii value for a, b, c, d, e and f are 61, 62, 63, 64, 65 and 66.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what if my string contains characters that cannot be expressed by ASCII, likes foreign characters? I think the comments of Sotirios and Remy answered my question perfectly.